# Inserting already formatted text into mysql table

Tags: mysql

I am new to mysql and was wondering if there is anyway to store already formatted text into a table on my mysql server db.

I know this may sound dumb but, i need to put in a paragraph that has bullets in it, and was wondering if it is possible to INSERT them into the table?

I am using the TEXT value right now and wondering if that is the correct route for this.

Comment: You can store any text you want in a table, MySQL doesn't interpret or modify it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can store formatted text (like HTML or Markdown) in a `TEXT` column as you can see on the [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/blob.html):

> `TEXT` values are treated as nonbinary strings (character strings). They have a character set other than binary, and values are sorted and compared based on the collation of the character set.

Comment: but i cannot simply copy and paste text with bullets into mysql using sql commands, im more asking along the lines of how i would input that so it would show those bullets in the table

Comment: Why not? You can insert anything you want, the bullets are just characters too. Even if the text is an HTML chunk, you can just insert it as you would do with a plain text.